# Client update after launching a game - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, auto-update

Im making a multiplayer game in unity, and because of that i want everyone that has the game to have the latest versión available.
It there a way to have it that it checks if there is a new update every time you open the game, and if there is one, it download it and applies it automatically?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: If we are talking about Unity3D specifics, you need to put in which Platform your Game Runs or at lease what Platform are you targeting since. Checking for updates runs differently from each platform. But you can use a tons of variety to set your current updated values. Such in Database. or even in website Get Method. Then check its equality. If there is a new one. Redirect <- this is where the platform specifics needs to be provided. As if Android. You will redirect them to PlayStore. For exe files, it is better if you have updater. For Web player, it is not a problem as it always checks n DL